# Horizontal lift of a vector field on a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, vector-fields, fiber-bundles

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g,\nabla)$ endowed with the Levi-Civita connection we define its frame bundle $\mathfrak{F}(M):= \bigsqcup_{p \in M}   \mathfrak{F}(M)_p$, where $\mathfrak{F}(M)_p$ is the space of the frames at $p$. It is possible to show that is a $GL(d,\mathbb{R})$ principal bundle.

A vector space on $X \in T_u \mathfrak{F}(M)$ is vertical if it is tangent to the fiber $\mathfrak{F}(M)_{\pi u}$ and it is called horizontal if it is the tangent vector of an horizontal curve on $\mathfrak{F}(M)$, i.e. a curve $\{u_t\}$ such that for any $e \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $\{u_te\}$ is $\nabla$-parallel to $\{\pi u_t\}$.

It is possible to show that the canonical projection $\pi : \mathfrak{F}(M) \xrightarrow{} M$ induces an isomorphism on the set of horizontal vectors $H_u \mathfrak{F}(M)$.

So given a tangent vector $X_x \in T_x M$ and a frame $u_x$ at $x$ there is an unique horizontal vector $X^o_x$ such that $d\pi X^o_x=X_x$. If $X$ is a vector field in $M$, $X^o$ is an horizontal vector field on $\mathfrak{F}(M)$, called the horizontal lift of $X$ to $u$.

In the case of a Lie group i know that there is a global section of the frame bundle and any vector field is complete, so i'm expecting the horizontal lift to be complete as well (am i right?).

I'm trying to express the horizontal lift of a generic vector field on a (matrix) Lie group $G$ w.r. to its global section. This section can be trivialized as $u_h=dL_h X_i$, where  $\{X_i\}$ are the generators of the Lie algebra of $G$.

I know that there is a natural bases for $H_u \mathfrak{F}(M)$ given by the vectors
$$
H_{e_i}(u_h):= \text{ the horizontal lift of } u_he \in T_{\pi u_h}M=T_h M \text{ to } u
$$

EDIT:
I notice that my question was very confusing, i apologies.

Given a local chart on a chart $(U,x^i)$ of $M$ this induces a local trivialization of the frame bundle. In particular, if $e_i$ is the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u \in \pi^{-1}(U)$ we have $u e_i= e^{j}_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$. We have that $(\partial_{x^i}, \partial_{e^i_j})$ is a bases for $T_u \mathfrak{F}(M)$. In this bases the fundamental vector fields can be described as
$$
H_{e_i}(u=(x,e))=e^j_i \partial_{x^j} - e^j_i e^l_m \Gamma^k_{ij}(x) \partial_{e^k_m}
$$
My questions is:
If there is a global section $v$ there is a way to obtain a global expression for the fundamental horizontal vector fields w.r. to this section, i.e. there is an expression for $H_{e_i}(v)$ in terms of the global section of the global trivialization?

Comment: This can be done for any principal bundle after fixing a connection one form (in particular the Levi-Civita connection induces a unique connection one form in the bundle of orthonormal frames). This is done explicitly in Kobayashi’s foundation of differential geometry, proposition 1.2 on page 65.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Horizontal", as opposed to a Vertical lift for example? I'm aware of several different kinds of categorical lifts (ie in algebraic topology, etc) but not sure which you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: It seems you have chosen some basis and you are saying horizontal to that? Some "Standard, natural" basis, it certainly seems fishy right from the start

Comment: @Snared Horizontal here means lifting a vector field on the base manifold to the a horizontal vector field in the bundle. This is clearly only possible up to a choice of connection one form (which determines horizontal subspaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that by complete you mean all integral curves of a vector field $X$ can be extended to all of  $\mathbb{R}$. I also haven't thought to much about this specific case before, so if I say something incorrect, my apologies.

You are correct that the frame bundle of a Lie group $G$ has a global section. In particular, this is because a basis for the Lie algebra determines a global frame, hence if $(T_1,\dots,T_n)\in T_eG\cong \mathfrak{g}$ is a basis for the Lie algebra, then the global section is given by:

$$s(g)=(L_{g*}T_1,\dots, L_{g*}T_n)$$

as at each point $g\in G$, this is a frame for $T_gG$. This gives us a global trivialization of the frame bundle for $G$, hence:

$$\mathfrak{F}(G)\cong G\times GL_n(\mathbb{R})$$

which is itself a Lie group so every vector field is complete, including horizontal lifts.

Ok so for a general principal $G$ bundle $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ how do we obtain a horizontal lift a vector field on $M$? Well we have that any connection one form determines a horizontal sub bundle $H \subset TP$, and it follows that $D_p\pi:H_p\rightarrow T_{\pi(p)}M$ is then an isomorphism for all $p\in P$. We thus fix a connection one form on $P$.
Given $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ we thus define a $X^H\in\mathfrak{X}(P)$ pointwise by:

$$X^H_p=(D_p\pi)^{-1}(X_{\pi(p)})$$

We need to show that this is smooth, so let $\phi$ be a bundle chart for an open neighborhood $U$ of $\pi(p)=x$. Let $\phi(p)=(x,h)$, then $D_p\phi:T_gP\rightarrow T_xM\oplus T_gG$ is an isomorphism. Let $\pi_U:U\times G$ be the projection onto $U$, and define a smooth section of the pullback bundle $\pi_U^*TU$ by:
\begin{align*}
Z:(U\times G)&\longrightarrow \pi_U^*TU\\
   (x,g)&\longmapsto ((x,g),X_x)
\end{align*}
which is smooth because $X$ is smooth, and takes values in $\pi^*_U TU\subset \pi^*_UTU\oplus \pi^*_GTG\cong T(U\times G)$, so $Z$ is actually a smooth section of $T(U\times G)$. It is then easy to see that:
\begin{align*}
 D_{(x,g)}\pi_U(Z_{(x,g)})=X_x
\end{align*}
Since $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, it follows that there exists a unique vector field $Y\in\mathfrak{X}(P_U)$ such that $\phi_*(Y)=Z$, hence for all $p\in P_U$:
\begin{align*}
D_p\phi(Y)=Z_{\phi(p)}
\end{align*}
So:
\begin{align*}
D_{\phi(p)}\pi_U\circ D_p\phi(Y)=X_{\pi(p)}
\end{align*}
however:
\begin{align*}
D_{\phi(p)}\pi_U\circ D_p\phi=D_p(\pi_U\circ \phi)=D_p\pi
\end{align*}
so:
\begin{align*}
D_p\pi(Y_p)=X_{\pi(p)}
\end{align*}
Since $X^H$ is uniquely determined, it follows that $X^H$ is locally the horizontal component of $Y$, and thus $X^H$ must be smooth. It follows that $X^H$ is the unique horizontal lift of $X$.

Regarding your question pertaining Lie groups, perhaps you can clarify what you mean specifically, because as I see it now, there's not a clear way to obtain the horizontal lift in terms of a global section. Indeed, sections determine bundle charts/local trivializations, but these bundle charts don't respect the horizontal lift (the above proof demonstrates this clearly) as that is determined by a connection one form. You could choose the flat connection, which exists in this case because the bundle is trivial, but in general it won't be a metric connection, and so can't be the Levi Civita connection.

If it helps at all, you can write the connection one form with on $G\times GL_n(\mathbb{R}) as:

$$(\phi^{-1*}\omega)_{(g,A)}=A^{-1}\pi_G^*\omega_{s(g)} A+\pi_{GL_n(\mathbb{R})}^*(A^{-1}dA)$$
where $\omega_s=s^*\omega$, $A\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, and $A^{-1}dA$ is the Maurer Cartan form on $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This clarify a bit my confusion about the argument.
My hope was that there is some nice "coordinate" expression of the horizzontal lift on terms of the global section.
I know that the fundamental horizontal lift can be expressed in local coordinates as
$$
H_i(u)=e^j_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}- e^j_l e^l_m \Gamma^k_{jl}\frac{\partial}{\partial e^k_m}
$$
In any chart of the frame bundle, but i'm doing this in the context of stochastic ODE on manifold and so localizing the equation can be a problem.

That's why i was thinking to use a global bases

Comment: Your coordinate expression looks more or less correct, and it’s obtained by writing my final formula in coordinates and setting it equal to zero. However, once you go to this trivialization, I’m pretty sure that the image your global section just becomes the identity on the $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$